# Как вывести последние три элемента модели из базы данных?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-mvc

Проблема такая: есть модель "News" с параметрами "NewsId", "Title" и "Text". 
В представлении я вывожу эти новости:

```
@foreach (News n in Model) 
  {
   <div class = "col-md-4">
    <h2>@n.Title</h2>
    <p>@n.Text</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Далее &raquo;</a></p>
   </div>
  }
```

В HomeController написал так:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 var news = db.News;
 retutn View(news);
}
```

А в представлении задействовал это:

```
@using library.Models;
@model IEnumerable<News>
```

Проблема в том, что он мне выводит все новости, а мне нужны только последние три. 
Большое спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: Например: `var news = db.News.Skip(Math.Max(0, db.News.Count() - 3));` Тут мы с помощью `.Skip()` пропускаем "число элементов в коллекции - 3", что должно оставить последние 3 элемента, они у вас дальше и отобразятся.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Напишите полученный результат в ответ.

Comment: Skip и Count тут совершенно не к месту, достаточно отсортировать по убыванию, и взять три записи. Order yDescending().Take(3).ToArray()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе Index(), в HomeController  надо записать

```
   var news = db.News.OrderBy(News => News.NewsId).Skip(Math.Max(0, db.News.Count() - 3));
   return View(news);
```

Все остальное остается как я и описывал выше.